# Is there a way to get past the error "TypeError: headers.map is not a function"?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

TypeError: headers.map is not a function

```
function TableComponent(headers, values) {
  if (!headers || !values) return null;
  const optionsPerPage = [2, 3, 4];
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(optionsPerPage[0]);
  console.log(headers);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <DataTable>
        {headers.map(({ title, numeric }) => <DataTable.Title key={title} numeric={numeric}>{title}</DataTable.Title>)}
        {values.map((value, index) => <DataTable.Row key={index}>
        {headers.map(({ title }) => <DataTable.Cell key={title}>{value[title]}</DataTable.Cell>)}
        </DataTable.Row>)}
          <DataTable.Pagination
            page={page}
            numberOfPages={3}
            onPageChange={(page) => setPage(page)}
            label="1-2 of 6"
            optionsPerPage={optionsPerPage}
            itemsPerPage={itemsPerPage}
            setItemsPerPage={setItemsPerPage}
            showFastPagination
            optionsLabel={'Rows per page'}
          />
      </DataTable>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Maybe I am using the wrong solution for this problem entirely. I am open to alternatives if this simply cannot work.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(headers)`?

Comment: {headers: Array(6), values: undefined}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, it looks like `headers` is an object and not an array, which explains "`headers.map` is not a function". Instead, use `headers.headers.map(...)` because `headers.headers` is an array.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Got a solution for this?